# Webscraping paginated website with different page layout using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to paginate through 200+ pages on this website and not all of them have the same layout. For example: GPA breakdown and SAT/ACT(in testing policy row) Super Scores are different across these schools. And for the harvard college page, SAT/ACT Super Scores just flat out don't show up. I'm having problems trying to format this for the csv because these data show up for one page but not for some other ones.

Links:
https://www.princetonreview.com/college/georgia-institute-technology-1022905
https://www.princetonreview.com/college/princeton-university-1024041
https://www.princetonreview.com/college/harvard-college-1022984

CSV file I currently have: https://ibb.co/Tc3DyFR This sample only shows the difference in Super Scores because I have not scraped GPA breakdown yet. However, both layouts are different across different pages.

Code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs-extra');

(async function main() {
try{
    var names = await (fs.readFileSync('names.csv', 'utf8')).split('\n');

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36');

    await page.goto('https://www.princetonreview.com/college/harvard-college-1022984#!admissions');
    //await fs.writeFile('out.csv', 'School Name,Applicants,Acceptance Rate,Average HS GPA,GPA: Over 3.75,GPA: 3.50-3.74,GPA: 3.25 - 3.49,GPA: 3.00 - 3.24,GPA: 2.50 - 2.99,GPA: 2.00 - 2.49,SAT Reading and Writing,SAT Math,ACT\n');

    await fs.appendFile('out.csv', `"${names[1]}",`);
    const numbers = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let nums = document.querySelectorAll('.number-callout');

        let arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(nums);
        let text_arr = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(arr[i].innerText == "")
                continue;
            text_arr.push(arr[i].innerText.trim());
        }
        return text_arr;
    });

    for(var e of numbers){
        await fs.appendFile('out.csv', `"${e}",`);
    }
    await fs.appendFile('out.csv', `\n`);
    //console.log(numbers);
    await browser.close();
}catch(e){
    console.log('our error', e);
}
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer:

Whenever you are paginating through separate style, you must stop thinking about a general solution at first.

Think of each block separately, and try to get the data one by one. This way you can format and break them as you want.

## Long Answer:

This looks a like a pretty big assignment/task to resolve in one question. However here is some lead to resolve this problem.

Our problem is, 
- The format is different across different pages.
- Some page has the data, some does not.
- We need to extract 8-10 specific data.

Let's say we want to extract **Superscore SAT** score, which is available on Priceton and Georgia but not Harvard page.

We need to search all them them specifically, or optimize the code to extract all data. There is not generalized way to magically knowing what's what.

```
// Let's grab all elements
[...document.querySelectorAll('div.number-callout')]
// And search for specific term
.find(e=>{
  // We can go upper level and find the link element 
  // since it's the only one identifying this data
  const parent = e.parentNode.querySelector('a')
  // if an element is found, we search for the text there
  if(parent) return parent.innerText.includes('Superscore SAT')
})
```

This will only return result on first two.
[image]

This also works with "Superscore ACT"

[image]

You can map through the elements and merge the data,

```
const data = {};
[...document.querySelectorAll('div.number-callout')].map(e=>{
  const parent = e.parentNode.querySelector('a');
    if(parent){
        if(parent.innerText.includes('Superscore ACT')) data["Superscore ACT"] = true;
        if(parent.innerText.includes('Superscore SAT')) data["Superscore SAT"] = true;
    }
});
```

Result:
[image]